# About F# TypeProvider Static Parameter Syntax

Tags: f#, type-providers

1. Why TypeProvider supports static parameters, how is this done, and does the f# compiler specifically support this feature?
2. I write a class myself, do not implement the ITypeProvider interface, can do the same effect?
3. The syntax of static parameters is not described in the f# language reference, is there any relevant help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking if the static parameters mechanism used in type providers can be used in ordinary F# code.

The short answer is no.

[Type providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/) are special: they are compiler plug-ins that provides types, properties, and methods for use in your code. Special rules apply to them.